# Does curl has a pagination limit

Tags: curl

Is there a pagination limit for curl?

I am executing below on a mac terminal and the resultset always display just 25 items where as via postman I am able to get complete set

```
curl -X GET --user USER:PASSWORD https://example.com/rest/api/1.0/foldername?size=677&limit=1000
```

I am not aware of one on curl or bash

Comment: solved it and its how you give query in a curl (nice learning)

`curl -X GET -G -u USER https://example.com/rest/api/1.0/foldername -d 'size=677' -d 'limit=1000'`

Comment: actually, that's not about curl or postman but the pagination system that the API you are consuming offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, there is not. perhaps theoretically, there may be some 64bit integer overflow bugs after downloading about 18.4 exabytes (2^64 bytes), but you're going to run into other problems long before you run into any download size limits of curl. (you can set your own limits with the `--max-filesize` parameter, though, but that parameter is unreliable)

the difference you're seeing has another cause. for example, in curl here, you're sending the `limit=1000` in the url, maybe when you're using postman, you're sending it in the POST body instead of the url, without realizing it? that would explain it. does removing `?size=677&limit=1000` from the url and adding `-d size=677 -d limit=1000` make a difference? now you moved the parameters from the url to the post body in curl (using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding) - other encodings include application/json and multipart/form-data encoding, if i were you, i'd inspect my postman request closely..